# query CouchDB data by several key and order data by another field

Tags: nosql, couchdb, cloudant

General idea, Is that I need to select data by several values and sort it by date.

I need to query couchdb something like this SQL query

```
Select * from TABLE where Val = "val1" OR Val = "val2" order by Date
```

So I have a map function looks like

```
if(doc.type == 'item'){
  emit([doc.val, doc.date], doc);
}
```

Think it should be something like

```
?startkey=[['val1','val2']]&endkey=[['val1','val2'],{}]
```

or

```
{keys: [['val1',{}],['val2',{}]]}
```

Is it possible? Maybe some other variannts exist - hot to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible in CouchDB. You will have to run two queries (possibly as a single bulk request) and perform the final ordering on the client (it is a linear-time operation).